# Like live editing of XHTML and CSS in firebug can we do live testing of javascript without leaving page?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, firebug

Like live editing of XHTML and CSS in firebug can we do live testing of javascript without leaving page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [firebug console](http://getfirebug.com/commandline) supports live execution of Javascript. You have full access to the page's state (variables, functions, etc) to inspect/execute/alter/etc.